# Is it possible to make a lightbulb light up by wetting your hands?

Tags: light, biopotential

I was recently watching an Electroboom video on free energy devices, but my question is not about any of that stuff.  [Here's the video.](https://youtu.be/15V0gUXUPko) At about 5:50 he claims and seemingly shows that he can light up a light bulb using his muscles and by wetting his hands.  Now this guy usually is pretty solid with his stuff, but when he did this, I was floored.  Did he make this up, or is he (and maybe others) some kind of mutant or something?  I tried it, and maybe I wasn't doing it quite the same way, but it didn't do anything.  Has anyone ever heard of this trick, or this ability?

Comment: fake.  Read the video comments

Comment: You do realize that he is making fun of free energy advocates, right?  The scene you refer to is just him taking it over the top.  None of the stuff he's showing you works.  It is all just tricks - he explains some of them later on in the video.  He is **laughing** at the free energy advocates, and all of their gullible followers.  So, the thing with "flapping his arm to make electricity" is complete and utter **nonsense.**

Comment: Fake.  Just watch to the end where he explains it, and refers you to the youtube channels of real EEs.

Comment: I don't think many people here on EE.SE understand that Tom is joking. But yeah.. funny.

Comment: Yeah, he was using a Tesla coil to light it, right?  I thought he was legit for a bit, went off to class and then it suddenly occurred to me.  Yeah I feel like an idiot, sorry.  I guess I really wanted to believe that it could be done.  I'll probably delete this question.

Comment: Or I may as well leave it.  It's kind of a question about electrical trickery, so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a trick. The light bulb contains batteries, and all you need to do is create a conductive path between the contacts in order to turn it on. Wetting the fingers is key; the arm-flapping has nothing to do with it.

They've been marketed recently as "blackout-proof" bulbs. They charge themselves from the AC when it's available, and the cute thing is that the wall switch still switches them on and off (under certain conditions) even when the AC is off.

Comment: Yeah, I see how that can be done now.  I guess that's the problem with someone saying that they have powers and can do that.  It needs to be a plain lightbulb and in laboratory conditions because you can fake it.